# Comcast upgrade - Lost Port Forwarding

Tags: wireless-networking, port-forwarding

I've been successfully using a NetGear wifi router for some time with my Comcast Xfinity service.  One thing I do is turn on port forwarding for one specific port to a computer on my internal network.

Recently Comcast upgraded my modem and it's now a modem and wireless router.  I've logged on with the unit and put it in bridge mode and disabled the wifi.  I've connected to a hardwired port directly from my existing NetGear router.

My NetGear router is serving up the Internet as expected.  It says it has an external IP.  But I can no longer get to that forwarded port from the outside.  When I try, I do get an entry in the router log, such as "[LAN access from remote] from 198.199.98.246:44215 to 192.168.1.102:80, Saturday, May 09,2015 09:36:21".  But the port is still showing as closed.

I know it's not closed.  I can get to it internally on the network from other internal IP's. *confused*

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this router so can't try but this is how I will approach - YMMV.

New routers come with built-in firewall. Try disabling firewall *temporarily* on your router and see if that resolves it - no matter it works or not be sure to enable firewall ASAP. If disabling FW resolves it then you know where you need to tinker.

Answer (score 0):

The the router plugged directly into the modem (which in your case is put in one unit but still acts as two) this is your gate way the ports open on the netgear router dont do anything because the ports are still blocked on the gate way you need to open the ports on the new router if you can't you can find some firmware you can flash on it that will allow you to. If you don't want to do that you can by a separate modem from the store and use that other wise you can just take down the fire wall in the camcast router because the port opening is making a hole in the fire wall on the netgear router so there is still a fire wall.